# How to get data-attribute in custom block include cms page?

Tags: magento2

I have create module.
i call it int cms page.

```
{{block class="Namespace/Module/Block/Custom" template="Namespace_Module::html/my.phtml" custom_id=1}}
```

how to get **custom_id** value? in `Namespace/Module/Block/Custom` or in **my.phtml**?

Comment: Try with : 
`$block->getData('custom_id');`

Comment: it works ? let me know if it still not works

Answer (score 3):

In your **.phtml** file you need to use block :

**Try below code :**

```
$custom_id = $block->getData('custom_id'); 
echo $custom_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

```
$block->getData('custom_id')
```

$this inside a template refers to the instance of the PHP template engine used for rendering the block, not the block itself.

Answer (score 0):

In `.phtml` file

```
$custom_id = $this->getData("custom_id");
```

In your Block file

```
public function __construct(
            \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context, 
            array $data = []
) {

    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
```

Comment: i tried it and $result null.